# Using rems in the HTML element

Tags: html, css, fonts, content-management-system

I am using rems on my document when building a new page for my company.

I built my page and it's time to take it into the CMS. 
Long story short I didnt think about how fonts would translate...

So when I declare:

```
html{
   font-size:62.5%;
}
p{
   font-size:2rem;
}
```

Everything is dandy.

But when I plugged my code into the CMS it has an undesirable effect. 
The font size looked great on my stuff but the templates text was super tiny.

My question is before I start changing stuff to test is it possible to set the percentage font size to the container? Leaving the html element alone and then have the children elements and the rems follow the container(parent)?

Comment: Read this beautiful article by Chris Coyier - https://css-tricks.com/rems-ems/

Comment: I couldn't help but notice you didn't mention which CMS you're using. What CSS does it use by itself and aren't its styles overriding yours? Also, have you checked the result in the browser with the developer tools, to see if both styles still in effect?

Comment: I actually found the issue. Someone threw an !important rule on the body from the template... so it was ignoring my rules. But the CMS is sitecore and I looked at everything in the chrome dev tools.